# python interpreter within emacs fails on simple test on __main__ (syntax error)

Tags: python, syntax

This small program runs well in Terminal :

```
mac2011% cat bug.py
print(__name__ == "__main__")
#if True:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("main")
else:
    print("not main")
mac2011% python bug.py
True
main
mac2011% python --version
Python 3.6.9 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

In Emacs:

```
mac2011% Emacs --version
GNU Emacs 26.3
mac2011% Emacs -q bug.py
```

the file opens in (Python ElDoc) mode.

Python menu

Start interpreter (C-c C-p)

Eval buffer (C-c C-c)

```
Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default,     Jul 30 2019, 13:42:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or     "license" for more information.
>>> python.el: native completion setup loaded
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/alba/Documents/projets/plot time series/bug.py", line 5
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Replacing `if __name__ == "__main__":` by `if True:`, there is no more error.

Replacing `"__main__"` by `"__main_"`, there is no error.

Can you reproduce the facts?

Do you have any explanation?

How to repair?

Same with Python 3.7.6.

My emacs comes from [Emacs for Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com/).

Same with emacs 28.0.50 that I have just built.

Comment: May reproduce it with GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.14.5) of 2019-09-04. Please consider a bug-report.

Comment: I have filed a bug report with GNU.  Meanwhile, I have noticed this: even the first line of the script, that should print True ou False, is not executed.  Indeed, the error will be the same, whatever the python file content.

Comment: Unless the if line is commented out.

Comment: This equivalent syntax works : `print("main") if __name__ == '__main__' else  print("not main")`

Comment: `print("main") if __name__ == "__main__" else print("not main")` does **not** work today with `Emacs 27.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `C-u C-c C-c`.

See `python-shell-buffer-substring` function docstring:

> When optional argument `NOMAIN` is non-nil everything under an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block will be removed.

And `python-shell-send-buffer`:

> When optional argument `SEND-MAIN` is non-nil, allow execution of
>   code inside blocks delimited by `if __name__== '__main__':`.
>   When called interactively `SEND-MAIN` defaults to nil, unless it’s
>   called with prefix argument.

So the code actually sent by `C-c C-c` is:

```python
print(__name__ == "__main__")
#if True:


else:
    print("not main")
```

Comment: Nice find, but the feature is pretty nasty IMO.

Comment: @NickD It allows to surpass some stuff if intended. Currently, the bug seems causing the opposite.

Comment: @NickD This behavior was added by http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=6da55e5931e899acb1b7da2206967aa56da3ca0f with really brief comment. Maybe it should do the opposite - strip if-name-main block when invoked with prefix argument.

Comment: True.  Admitting that Emacs has to modify the code, for a reason that is not yet completely clear to me, at least it should do it cleanly, i. e., remove the full block `if [elif...] else` and maybe issue a warning.  This might finally be a bug.

Comment: Reading the Git page, I notice a loop hole in the filtering, where the alternative syntax `print("main") if __name__ == '__main__' else print("not main")` goes through.

Comment: That loop no longer seems to exist. `print("main") if __name__ == "__main__" else print("not main")` does **not** work today with `Emacs 27.1`. Both `C-c C-c` and `C-u C-c C-c` print `main`.